# QueryFetchArrayAll from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am pulling out data from my "facebook" table using this code that I then display in a table using the `foreach()` function:

```
$orders = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT id,url,c_amount,amount,date,status FROM `facebook` WHERE `user`='".$data['id']."' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 30");
```

How would I go about pulling out data from multiple tables, for example from the "facebook" AND "twitter" table and then displaying it at the same time in my table?

Here is my full code for those that would need that:

```
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td># (ID)</td>
                        <td>URL</td>
                        <td>Current Amount</td>
                        <td>Amount Wanted</td>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>Status</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        <?
          $orders = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT id,url,c_amount,amount,date,status FROM `facebook` WHERE `user`='".$data['id']."' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 30");
          if(!$orders){ echo '<tr><td colspan="6" align="center"><b>Noting found!</b></td><tr>';}else{
          foreach($orders as $order){
        ?>
        <?
            if($order['status'] == 0){
                $status = '<label style="color: #999999;">Waiting for supplier</label>';
            }
            elseif ($order['status'] == 1) {
                $status = '<label style="color: #f0ad4e;">In progress</label>';
            }
            elseif ($order['status'] == 2) {
                $status = '<label style="color: #e25856;">Canceled/Refunded</label>';
            }
            elseif ($order['status'] == 3) {
                $status = '<label style="color: #428bca;">Pending admin review</label>';
            }
            else{
                $status = '<label style="color: #94b86e;">Completed</label>';
            }
        ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?=$order['id']?></td>
                        <td><?=$order['url']?></td>
                        <td><?=$order['c_amount']?></td>
                        <td><?=$order['amount']?></td>
                        <td><?=date('Y-m-d h:i',$order['date'])?></td>
                        <td><?=$status?></td>
                    </tr><?}}?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Do the `facebook` and `twitter` tables have anything in common?  Usually you would just `JOIN` them together.

Comment: They have the exact same structure but not data.
EDIT: Do you mean like this: FROM facebook JOIN twitter WHERE...?

Comment: If you're not trying to join by users, then as these answers suggest, you'd union the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UNION` keyword.

Please note that both queries should have the same fields count and the same fields types.

Example :

```
$orders = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll(
    "SELECT id,url,c_amount,amount,date,status FROM `facebook` WHERE `user`='" 
    . $data['id'] 
    . "' UNION 
    SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5 FROM `twitter` WHERE some_condition "
);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work, I get the "Noting found!" text inside that table instead of data from facebook/twitter.

Comment: @user3604070 Normally your query fails! Try executing it in `phpmyadmin` for example, or just tell us what is your `$db` object?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a union

```
$orders = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT id,url,
c_amount,amount,date,status FROM `facebook` 
WHERE `user`='".$data['id']."'
join ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 30
UNION
SELECT id,url,
c_amount,amount,date,status FROM `twitter` 
WHERE `user`='".$data['id']."'
join ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 30");
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried your code too but I get the "Nothing found!" text inside that atble instaed of data from facebook/twitter.

Comment: Do you get results for the individual queries without the union?